# regx - extracting everything between an underscore and a dot from text

Tags: regex

I am trying to extract everything between the `_` and the `.` in this text:

```
CIL20150424_NSGS02RPK.dat
CIL20150424_NSU01MAH.dat
```

to give me these matches:

```
NSGS02RPK
NSU01MAH
```

I am using this [site](http://www.regexr.com/) and the best I can do is locate the `_` using the negitive look ahead:

```
\d(_=?)
```

but this selects the 4 also `4_`.

How do I just select everything between the `_` and the `.` in this text?

Comment: `_\w* ` this selcts what I want except it includes the `_`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex matches your target:

```
(?<=_).*?(?=\.)
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/9mwWe4WJk6).

The regex uses a look behind for the underscore, a *reluctant* quantifier (in case there's more than one per line), and a look ahead for a dot (which you must escape to match a literal dot).

---

btw your attempt at a look ahead `(_=?)` is not a look ahead, it's a captured (bracketed) underscore followed by an optional equals sign.

Comment: tks that works! why does that work in your live demo and not in my link?

Comment: @HattrickNZ: `lookbehinds` are not supported in `javascript`.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it by capturing the part you want as a group `_([^.]+)`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
[^_]+_([^\.]+)\.
```

maybe i'm missing something. this skips everything up to the underscore, then captures everything between the underscore and the period.

Comment: not sure this is exactly what I want as get a slightly different result to Bohemian below. it gives me match groups , match1 match2.

Comment: This should only give you one match group, which is what you asked for in the question: you only wanted the text between the _ and the .

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple regex like below and grab the content from the capturing group:

```
_(.*)[.]
or
_(.*)\.     it's up to you to choose what you like most
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/jJ0fI7/1)**

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Match information

```
MATCH 1
1.  [12-21] `NSGS02RPK`
MATCH 2
1.  [38-46] `NSU01MAH`
```